# minikube mount working but not listed in df -h

Tags: windows, kubernetes, minikube, nextcloud, mount-point

I've mounted my windows host folder lab-dev-data to /mnt/data in my minikube installation (minikube mount C:\lab-dev-data:/mnt/data --port=50273 --uid 33 --gid 33)
The mount is working and files are showing up. Issues is that the mount point isn't listed when running df -h in the minikube installation (minikube ssh)

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           2.2G  743M  1.4G  35% /
devtmpfs        1.1G     0  1.1G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G   84K  1.2G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           483M   15M  469M   3% /run
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.2G  8.0K  1.2G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1        17G  4.8G   12G  30% /mnt/sda1
```

This causes my nextcloud deployment to think there is not storage space left reporting insufficiënt space errors in the log when trying to upload files.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

I'm running a nextcloud deployment with the following config:

```
#Nextcloud Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: lab-dev
  name: nextcloud 
  labels:
    app: nextcloud 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nextcloud 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nextcloud
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: nextcloud-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim: 
          claimName: nextcloud-pvc
      - name: nextcloud-files  
        hostPath:
          # directory location on host
          path: /mnt/data/nextcloud
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
      containers:
        - image: nextcloud:apache
          name: nextcloud 
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: redis
            - name: MYSQL_HOST
              value: mariadb 
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: MYSQL_DATABASE
                  name: mariadb-secrets
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
                  name: mariadb-secrets
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: MYSQL_USER
                  name: mariadb-secrets
            - name: NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
                  name: mariadb-secrets 
            - name: NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_USER
              value: "admin"
            - name: NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS 
              value: ${LoadBalancerIP} 
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/www/html
              name: nextcloud-storage
            - mountPath: /var/www/html/data
              name: nextcloud-files
```

I've tried multiple combinations when mounting and changing the owner/group of the mounted folder to no avail. i can not get it to report the available capacity to the nextcloud pod

Comment: what is the output of the short command `minikube mount C:\lab-dev-data:/mnt/data`  ?